# i need to display a drop down box on selection of a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to display a **drop down box** on selection of a particular **radio button** and hide it for another button!could anyone help me with its code in jquery/javascript??

Comment: You should share the relevant code and what you have tried.

Comment: What's your html? How far did you get before you got stuck? Can you show us your attempt(s), then we can help you learn.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `HTML` like so:

```
<p class="help">Selection:</p>
    <div id='buttons'>
        <label><input type="radio" name="select" id="option1" /> Option 1 </label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="select" id="option2" /> Option 2</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="select" id="option3" /> Option 3</label>
    </div>
    <div id="list">
        <label>Please Select From the List: 
            <select id="mySelect">
                <option>True</option>
                <option>False</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>​
</p>
```

Then you could write some `Jquery` like so:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $("#option1, #option2, #option3").click(
            function()
            {
                if (this.id == "option3")
                    $("#mySelect").hide();
                else
                    $("#mySelect").show();
            });
    });​
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AVFuY/3/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function show(){
  var element = document.getElementById('numbers');
  element.style.display = 'inline';
}

function hide(){
  var element = document.getElementById('numbers');
  element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show();">Show</button>
<button onclick="hide();">Hide</button>
<select id="numbers">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>  
</select>
```